# Android display images from a specific folder

Tags: android, android-studio, gallery, android-image

I need to display the images that are in a specific folder on the SD card.
I want to do it with a button and display the gallery. But, I don't know how to do it. I found some solution like this, but that solution didn't work for me:

```
public void openFolder(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            +"/pictures/miscursos/");
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
}
```

This just opens all the images, but not the folder that I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code will only opens the folder. You have to use `GallerView` or `GridView` with the help of `Adapter` you can set images to `ListView` or `GridView`. You have to give correct path in-order to open the folder you want.
[GridView loading photos from SD Card - refer this link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/07/gridview-loading-photos-from-sd-card.html)